# How to pass a parameter to the hibernate AttributeConverter

Tags: java, hibernate

If I have a `AttributeConverter` that changes the length of the input before persisting it in the database, what would be the correct way to make sure that the modified input doesn't exceed the maximum length allowed by that column (without hardcoding it in the converter) ?

```java
@Column(length = 1024)
@Convert(converter = MyConverter.class)
private String comment;

public class MyConverter implements AttributeConverter<String, String> {

   @Override
   public String convertToDatabaseColumn(String attribute) {
      return "hello world " + attribute;
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Does Hibernate not automatically check the length of the conversion's result?

Comment: Well I guess this is my question. And I'm assuming it depends on whether I put `@Length` or  `@size` or `@Column(length)`.

Comment: So you want a converter that works for any length set by either `@Length` or `@Size` or `@Column(length)` on any `String` entity column?

Comment: Basically I want everything to behave as if there were no Converter. When there is no converter:
* I am able to set the length of my column easily, by annotation (what the correct annotation is, I don't know)
* There is a meaningful exception if the string you try to persist has a bigger length than the column size.

However the converter changes the input length, and I suspect that (depending on the annotation, maybe) the check is made before the converter happens.

Comment: What would be the desired behavior when extending String's length exceeds column length?

Comment: I guess the same behaviour as if there were no Converter would be a nice outcome ? That's what I had in mind anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you want with hibernate [custom basic type](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-custom-type) that implements `DynamicParameterizedType` interface.

Below you can see a simple example of declaration custom type that read the `length` property of @Column annotation.

```java
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.persistence.Column;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor;
import org.hibernate.usertype.DynamicParameterizedType;
import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;

public class PersistableString implements UserType, DynamicParameterizedType
{
   private int sqlType;
   private int columnLength;

   public PersistableString()
   {
      this.sqlType = Types.VARCHAR;
   }

   @Override
   public void setParameterValues(Properties parameters)
   {
      ParameterType reader = (ParameterType) parameters.get(PARAMETER_TYPE);
      this.columnLength = getLength(reader);
   }

   private int getLength(ParameterType reader)
   {
      int length = -1; // default length
      for (Annotation annotation : reader.getAnnotationsMethod()){
         if (annotation instanceof Column) {
            length =  ((Column) annotation).length();
         }
      }
      return length;
   }

   @Override
   public int[] sqlTypes()
   {
      return new int[] {sqlType};
   }

   @Override
   public Class<?> returnedClass()
   {
      return String.class;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException
   {
      return Objects.equals(x, y);
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException
   {
      return Objects.hashCode(x);
   }

   /*
      This method will be called when hibernate initializes your entity's
      field from the appropriate database table row
   */
   @Override
   public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs,
         String[] names,
         SharedSessionContractImplementor session,
         Object owner) throws HibernateException, SQLException 
   {
      // you can use this.columnLength here
      return rs.getString(names[0]);
   }

   /*
      This method will be called when hibernate persists your entity's field
      to the appropriate database table row
   */
   @Override
   public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st,
         Object value,
         int index,
         SharedSessionContractImplementor session) throws HibernateException, SQLException
   {
      // you can use this.columnLength here
      if (value == null) {
         st.setNull(index, sqlType);
      }
      else {
         String val = (String) value;
         st.setString(index, val);
      }
   }

   @Override
   public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException
   {
      return value;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isMutable()
   {
      return false;
   }

   @Override
   public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException
   {
      return Objects.toString(value);
   }

   @Override
   public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner) throws HibernateException
   {
      return cached;
   }

   @Override
   public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner) throws HibernateException
   {
      return original;
   }
}
```

and usage:

```java
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;


@Entity
@Table
public class Account
{

   @Column(name = "acc_name", length = 50)
   @Type(type = "com.example.hibernate.PersistableString")
   private String name;

   @Column(name = "acc_pass", length = 30)
   @Type(type = "com.example.hibernate.PersistableString")
   private String pass;

   @Column(name = "acc_email", length = 355)
   @Type(type = "com.example.hibernate.PersistableString")
   private String email;
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. And what if the annotation is @Length or @Size?

Comment: @BobJI I completely rewrote my answer. It looks like [JPA 2.1 AttributeConverters](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-jpa-convert) does not support functionality what you want. But you can achieve it by using hibernate custom basic types.

Comment: Wow this looks very complicated. Is there no other way to make sure that what's about to be persisted doesn't exceed the column length ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not aware about such way.